# Python prints string with "+" sign in between

Tags: python, string, unicode

I extracted comments made in a website by converting the POST payload from the website to JSON and extracting the value in the comments field in Python.

The JSON looks something like this:

```
{
    .
    .
    "comment": "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog"
    .
    .
}
```

When I print the comment using the `print()` function, this is how the comment is printed: The+Quick+Brown+Fox+Jumped+Over+The+Lazy+Dog

The type of the comment seems to be 'unicode'. I have tried everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083374/how-to-decode-a-unicode-string-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols) but those don't solve my problem.

I am using python 2.7. Right now I am printing it for debugging purposes but I want to store it in a database later. So I would need a permanent solution to convert unicode to string.

EDIT: I use `var = json.loads(payload_from_POST)` to convert the POST payload to JSON. Then I extract the value of "comment" by var['comment'].

Comment: what do you get if you do print repr(your comment string) ?

Comment: some url encoding somewhere didn't get unencoded

Comment: @user1753919 I get 'u'' followed by the string with plus signs between the words

Comment: As @wim says, translating space to `+` is part of URL encoding. So something is not doing the necessary URL decoding before processing the JSON. Post your code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: one solution is to replace the "+" with " " using replace command.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited my question

Comment: payload_from_post... what is that exactly? You are implementing server side code, right? Where did you get the post data, exactly?

Comment: If you're writing server-side code, there are libraries to parse the POST data.

Comment: @Barmar no I am just writing client side. I have no control over the server I am getting the data from

Comment: How does a client get POST data from the server? POST data goes from the client to the server. Show how you're setting `payload_from_POST`.

Comment: @Barmar I get POST payload through a web hook (github webhook). When an event happens in my Pull Request, I get a POST message from the github web hook I had setup.

Comment: @user1753919: No

Comment: @SriHariVignesh: Present your [MCVE]. That is a requirement

Comment: @SriHariVignesh A web hook is server-side code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of parsing a request string into an appropriate dictionary representation. To do so, you can use the `parse_qs` function.

In Python 2,

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

var = parse_qs(payload_from_POST)
print var['comment'][0]
```

In Python 3

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

var = parse_qs(payload_from_POST)
print(var['comment'][0])
```

An important note: `parse_qs` will return a JSON that maps keys to **lists**, NOT strings. So in order to actually print "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog", you have to access `var['comment'][0]`, because `var['comment']` would just return you a list with one element in it.